# Scroll functionality for table created created using js

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have a table here created using JS dynamically, it contains data more than what a screen shows so I need to implement scroll functionality and the main thing is I also need **table width to be 100%**. Please anyone?

```js
var table = $('#mydemo1');
          
            for (var i = 0; i <= result.length; i++) 
            {
             doc1=result[i];
                              
                 var tbody = $("<tbody>").appendTo(table);
                 var tr = $("<tr>").appendTo(tbody);
           var td = $("<td>").html(doc1.Name).data(doc1).appendTo(tr);   

            }
```

```css
  .mytdemo1 td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 7px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:red;color:#444;background-color:#F7FDFA;}
.mytdemo1 td:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
      color: #ccc;
   }
.mytdemo1 th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 7px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:red;color:#fff;background-color:#26ADE4;}
.mytdemo1 .mytdemo1-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
```

```html
<div class="empl" id="table-scroll"> 
  
 <table class="mytdemo1" id="mydemo1" style="display:none;"> 
 <thead>
 <tr><th>Employee Name</th></tr>
 </thead>
 
 </table> 
 
 </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you actually mean but you can try `overflow: scroll;` and `width: 100%;` or `width: 100vw;`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to set in the parent element of the table (probably a div) the following style:

```
/* style to table's parent */
overflow: auto;
width: 100%;
max-height: /* your desired height */
```

And this style in the table:

```
width: inherit;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you want to scroll without the scroll bar taking fixed place on the side.

Use:

```
.vertically_scrollable{  
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

as it will only show the vertical scroll bar on top when necessary.